# how can I decipher an error message related to #+BEGIN_SRC?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I got this error message when exporting to html in `org-mode`:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument processp nil)
process-command(nil)
shell-mode()
funcall(shell-mode)
...
```

After googling for a while, [this post](http://osdir.com/ml/emacs-orgmode-gnu/2013-08/msg00323.html) helped me resolve the error.  I only needed to change:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
...
#+END_SRC
```

to

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash
...
#+END_SRC
```

However, I still want to know how I can understand the error messages better so that I can resolve it myself.  How can I do this?

Comment: Well, you *did* resolve it yourself.  Honestly, you did what you were supposed to do: hunt around for an explanation for what seemed like a cryptic error message.  It hints at the problem being related to `shell-mode`; `#+BEGIN_SRC` is looking for source code.  `bash` is a shell (like `sh` or `zsh`) but, to my knowledge, there is no `shell` shell.  Hence the errors.